# Conversion of string to list from a file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, string-conversion

I have a file in which the data(list) looks something like this

```
[5,[5,[5,100,-200],200,-400],300,-500]
```

Now when I read this file in an angular application, the file contents would be converted to string and hence would return a string object which would look something like this

```
"[5,[5,[5,100,-200],200,-400],300,-500]"
```

Is there a way where I can convert this back to the list in which it was originally present?

There is one approach but the solution is for a different problem. If my file has data

```
200
300
400
500
```

Then I can split this string by using

```
var newData = fileContent.split('\n');
desiredList = []
for(var z=0;z<newData.length;z++){
        desiredList.push(parseInt(newData[z]))
    }
```

The desired list would give me a list which I wanted. But for the question which I asked is there any approach?

Comment: `JSON.parse("[5,[5,[5,100,-200],200,-400],300,-500]")`

Comment: as long as your list is a JSON compatible array structure the following witll work:  `var list = JSON.parse(string);`

Comment: @dandavis  thank you. The solution works :)

Comment: @PatrickDenny thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse("[5,[5,[5,100,-200],200,-400],300,-500]")` should convert it to JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()`

```js
var str = "[5,[5,[5,100,-200],200,-400],300,-500]";
var jsonArr = eval(str);
console.log(jsonArr);
```

Comment: there's no need to use eval when you have valid JSON, which is faster to parse than evaluate...

Comment: Do not use eval() unless inevitable, beside others for security reasons...